# Default dimensions for development on TV

Tags: android, android-resources

Currently the [official design website](http://developer.android.com/design/style/iconography.html) indicates 5 types of screen densities.

These densities range from MDPI- XXHPDI.

I have also read in parts on the reference that there is also another identifier **TVDPI**

Does someone know the ratio difference between the the former and the latter?

- e.g. mdpi relates to 3 times XXHDPI
- mdpi relates to ? times TVDPI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`1 mdpi` relates to `1.33 times tvdpi`. Go [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) for more information.

**From the docs:**

*If you find it necessary to provide tvdpi resources, you should size them at a factor of 1.33 times mdpi. For example, a 100px x 100px image for mdpi screens should be 133px x 133px for tvdpi.*

Answer (score 0):

**Referenced link** from the accepted anwser indicates the following regadring **TVDPI**:

> Resources for screens somewhere between mdpi and hdpi; approximately
>   213dpi. This is not considered a "primary" density group. It is mostly
>   intended for televisions and most apps shouldn't need it—providing
>   mdpi and hdpi resources is sufficient for most apps and the system
>   will scale them as appropriate. If you find it necessary to provide
>   tvdpi resources, you should size them at a factor of 1.33*mdpi. For
>   example, a 100px x 100px image for mdpi screens should be 133px x
>   133px for tvdpi.